# Creating dynamic drop-down list boxes in Rails but data not from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I want to create 2 dynamic drop-down list boxes but the data for both of the text boxes are from API response not from the local database.When I select the data in first drop-down,a REST call has to be made depends on the data selected and the response has to be shown in the second drop down.
Is there any way to do this?

---

I'm searching for this a long time but I'm able to do like this only using the data from local database.

Comment: You have to write controller code to respond to the request, so in that code, don't use data from the db.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Slicedpan. Can you pls explain me with a small example?

Comment: Post what the code you use to do this using the database data, and i'll explain how to alter it to not use data from the database

Comment: Technically speaking, you don't even need a controller. You can use plain simple JavaScript and perform the REST call from js.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at select2, which does an ajax call to a controller action, which then calls the APIs in question.